# Pc based stopwatch?

Tags: stopwatch

I would like to time myself with regards to the time I spend on a particular task.

Is there a software that could act like a stopwatch or something on similar lines.

This way I want to gauge how efficiently and fast I can do a particular task and if necessary optimize it to reduce the time to the minimum possible.

Any additional features would be a bonus.

Answer (score 2):

There is a stopwatch program called… [Stopwatch](http://expect.sourceforge.net/stopwatch/). It may already be distributed with your operating system, e.g. [stopwatch](http://packages.ubuntu.com/stopwatch) [image: Install stopwatch].

But maybe you're looking for a time-tracking program, such as [gnotime](http://gttr.sourceforge.net/) ([gnotime](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gnotime) [image: Install gnotime]) or [ktimetracker](http://userbase.kde.org/Ktimetracker)
([ktimetracker](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ktimetracker) [image: Install ktimetracker])

Comment: I didn't mention it earlier but do you have windows equivalent of these?

Comment: @Kevin: I don't. When you ask for a software recommendation, you should say on what OS you want the software to run.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ManicTime](http://www.manictime.com/). The standard edition is free and available for Windows 7, Windows Vista and Windows XP.

Comment: Seems to be good, will try it out!!

Answer (score 0):

I found this one along the way. Its called [XNote Stopwatch](http://www.xnotestopwatch.com/)
Has excel integration and external input too via serial port.
Have to still try it out though.